# How to set a script to execute when a port receives a message

Tags: bash, shell-script, networking, daemon

I'm wondering how to get a shell script to listen in on a certain port (maybe using netcat?). Hopefully so that when a message is sent to that port, the script records the message and then runs a function.

Example:

1. Computer 1 has the script running in the background, the script opened port 1234 to incoming traffic
2. Computer 2 sends message "hello world" to port 1234 of computer 1
3. Script on Computer 1 records the message "hello world" to a variable $MESSAGE
4. Script runs function now that variable $MESSAGE has been set

How do I go about doning this?

Answer (score 23):

Should be possible with `socat`.

Write such a script "getmsg.sh" to receive one message via stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash
read MESSAGE
echo "PID: $$"
echo "$MESSAGE"
```

Then run this `socat` command to invoke our script for each tcp connection on port 7777:

```
socat -u tcp-l:7777,fork system:./getmsg.sh
```

Send a test message from another shell:

```
echo "message 1" | netcat localhost 7777
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Rewritten and tested now ;)

Comment: I was inspired by your solution and found a way that works with netcat: nc -l 7777 | ./getmsg.sh

Comment: Glad to hear that.  But `netcat` exists after one connection. `socat` would do the same if you remove ",fork" from my command line.

Answer (score 13):

## The UCSPI-TCP way

There are toolsets other than netcat.  Here are how to use a few of them.  They all presume the existence of a `service` script that runs your `func`, whatever that may be:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r MESSAGE
do
    echo 1>&2 "${TCPREMOTEIP}" "${TCPREMOTEPORT}" rx "${MESSAGE}"
    func
done
```

The `TCPREMOTEIP` and `TCPREMOTEPORT` environment variables are defined by the UCSPI-TCP protocol.

The script is spawned as an individual process per TCP connection using the various toolsets.  In what follows, the tools are shown as used within a short script.  Such a script, conventionally named `run`, is how one would run them under a daemontools-family service manager.  They can of course be invoked directly.

### Bernstein ucspi-tcp

With Daniel J. Bernstein's ucspi-tcp, `tcpserver` spawns the `service` script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
exec tcpserver -v -P -R -H -l 0 0.0.0.0 7777 ./service
```

There are IPv6-capable enhanced versions of Bernstein ucspi-tcp.  With Erwin Hoffman's, `tcpserver` attempts to handle both IPv4 and IPv6 in one (if the operating system supports this, a few do not) and spawns the `service` script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
exec tcpserver -v -P -R -H -l 0 ::0 7777 ./service
```

### Bercot s6-networking, s6, and execline

With Laurent Bercot's s6-networking, `s6-tcpserver4` and `s6-tcpserver6` handle IPv4 and IPv6 separately, and spawn the `service` script:

```
#!/command/execlineb
s6-tcpserver4 -v 0.0.0.0 7777 
./service
```

```
#!/command/execlineb
s6-tcpserver6 -v ::0 7777 
./service
```

One can build up more complex servers by interposing tools such as `s6-tcpserver-access` and `s6-applyuidgid` in the chain immediately before `./service`.

### nosh UCSPI tools

With the nosh toolset, `tcp-socket-listen` listens on the TCP socket, again handling IPv4 and IPv6 simulataneously if the operating system supports doing so, and chains to `tcp-socket-accept` which in turn spawns the `service` script:

```
#!/bin/nosh
tcp-socket-listen --combine4and6 :: 7777
tcp-socket-accept --verbose --localname 0
./service
```

Or one runs two separate processes, on operating systems such as OpenBSD:

```
#!/bin/nosh
tcp-socket-listen 0.0.0.0 7777
tcp-socket-accept --verbose --localname 0
./service
```

```
#!/bin/nosh
tcp-socket-listen :: 7777
tcp-socket-accept --verbose --localname ::
./service
```

One can build up more complex servers by interposing tools such as `ucspi-socket-rules-check` and `setuidgid` in the chain.

```
#!/bin/nosh
tcp-socket-listen --combine4and6 :: 7777
setuidgid unprivileged-user
tcp-socket-accept --verbose --localname 0
ucspi-socket-rules-check --verbose
./service
```

### Pape ipsvd

With Gerrit Pape's ipsvd, `tcpsvd` spawns the `service` script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
exec tcpsvd -v 0.0.0.0 7777 ./service
```

## UCSPI-UDP

The common `service` script can handle when standard input is a *stream* socket.  But you didn't specify TCP explicitly.

Although some of the aforementioned toolkits can be used to build UDP servers in similar fashion to how one can use them to build TCP servers (c.f. `udp-socket-listen` in nosh), it's tricky to build the actual service program with shell script, as the shell's builtins do not necessarily cope well when standard input is a *datagram* socket.

## Further reading

- Protocol:

  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[The gen on the UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/UCSPI.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
  - Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). *[UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://cr.yp.to/proto/ucspi.txt)*.  cr.yp.to.
- toolsets:

  - Daniel J. Bernstein. *[ucspi-tcp](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html)*.  cr.yp.to.
  - [s6-networking](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/index.html).  Laurent Bercot.  skarnet.org.
  - [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/index.html).  Laurent Bercot.  skarnet.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[nosh](http://jdebp.info/Softwares/nosh/).*  Softwares.
  - [ipsvd](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/index.html).  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.
- reference manuals:

  - Daniel J. Bernstein. *[The `tcpserver` program](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html)*.  ucspi-tcp.
  - Erwin Hoffmann.  [`tcpserver`](http://fehcom.de/ipnet/ucspi-tcp6/tcpserver.html).  *ucspi-tcp6*.  fehcom.de.
  - [`s6-tcpserver4`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver4.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6-networking*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`s6-tcpserver6`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver6.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6-networking*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`s6-tcpserver-access`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver-access.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6-networking*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`s6-applyuidgid`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-applyuidgid.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6*.  skarnet.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`tcpserver`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/tcpserver.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`tcp-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/tcp-socket-listen.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`tcp-socket-accept`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/tcp-socket-accept.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`ucspi-socket-rules-check`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/ucspi-socket-rules-check.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`setuidgid`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/setuidgid.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`udp-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/udp-socket-listen.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - [`tcpsvd`](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html).  *ipsvd*.  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.

Comment: for The gen on the UNIX Client-Server Program Interface: http://jdebp.info/FGA/UCSPI.html

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with `udpsvd` which is available on Ubuntu/ Debian ([see manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/udpsvd.8.html)) as well as built-in to busybox.  Example:

```
# simple UDP "echo" on port 9998
udpsvd 0.0.0.0 9998 cat
```

Replace `cat` with your shell script to execute, stdin is the packet.

With `netcat`, you can run in a loop to keep listening, and pass each packet to `myscript`:

```
 while true; do nc -ul 9998 | myscript.sh; done
```

If you wanted to pass all received packets as a stream to a single invocation of your script:

```
# this will keep listening instead of terminating the process:
nc -kul 9998 |myscript.sh
```