# Create a background daemon to listen for incoming SSH requests

Tags: ssh, gentoo, daemon

I'm just trying to see if this is possible before I start working on it. Here's the scenario, I want the server to be constantly listening for SSH requests (which I'm sure it already does, I just don't know where) and depending on the IP address of the incoming machine either do nothing or take an action before the SSH attempt is started.

Note: I want to allow every ssh attempt (with correct credentials of course) into the system, I just want to be able to perform some action before that happens. Running Gentoo Base 2.4.1

Comment: The listening is done by the `ssh` daemon and it does already log each connection. What is the action you want to do? An example?

Comment: The action is actually to disable logging, I want to make it so only devices I don't know get logged

Comment: Example would be: I log on with my own device and before anything about my ssh attempt gets logged, logging is turned off, then I complete the ssh and logging is re-enabled

Comment: Begin by reading `man sshd sshd.conf`, then download the source and ... `sshd`, by default, listens on `TCP/22`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serve up a service over TCP, some program has to call `listen()` to get a *listening socket*, and that same program or one related to it has to call `accept()` to accept the individual incoming TCP connections as further *connected sockets*.
OpenSSH's server dæmon operates in two basic modes in this regard.

- It is started without the `-i` option.  It executes `listen()` and then loops repeatedly calling `accept()` and `fork()`ing off child processes for every incoming connection.
- It is started with the `-i` option.  It expects something else to have called `listen()`, `accept()`, and `fork()`, and to have executed it with the connected socket as an already-open file descriptor.

The latter mode is the `nowait` style of TCP server under the old `inetd` superserver, the `Accept=yes` style of TCP socket unit in systemd, and the style of server that works with Daniel J. Bernstein's UCSPI-TCP.

The former mode unfortunately *does not* correspond with the `wait` style of TCP server under `inetd` and the `Accept=no` style of TCP server under systemd.  OpenSSH does not speak the `LISTEN_FDS` protocol and does not acknowledge already-open file descriptors for listening sockets.  Additionally unfortunate is that some people encourage this mode of use and it is thus likely the way that OpenSSH is set up to run on your system.

Because what you want is the latter mode.

You wrap `ssh -i` inside something else that looks at the information about the remote end of the connnection and does stuff based upon what it finds before then `exec()`ing `ssh -i`.  (UCSPI-TCP makes this very easy, as the remote end information is put into environment variables.)  You then invoke the wrapper instead of invoking `ssh -i` directly.

The particulars of doing this are up to you, because they depend from things that you haven't told us, such as what service management system you are using.
It could range widely from a drop-in snippet with a different `ExecStart` in a systemd service unit through a revised `xinetd` config file to a replacement `./service` program in a nosh service bundle.

An alternative approach, which will work with the non-`-i` invocation mode but which does not generalize beyond certain options of one particular program giving one particular service (as the aforegiven approach in contrast does), is to use the `Match` mechanism in the `sshd_config` file.  This cannot do anything except set a subset of OpenSSH options, including the log level, and of course doesn't apply even to other SSH server softwares, let alone to other types of service.

Be sensible in your wrapper.
The SSH connection proper is not up and running at the time that it executes; you should *not* (for security) read *any* data from the network connection, nor write any to it; and the only things to be doing are checking addresses/ports against lists and thence configuring per-session settings in some way.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[The gen on the UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/UCSPI.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
- Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). *[UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://cr.yp.to/proto/ucspi.txt)*.  cr.yp.to.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`ucspi-socket-rules-check`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ucspi-socket-rules-check.xml).  nosh toolset.  Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315470/5132